# How do I fix Fragment already added in my code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I open a `dialog fragment` from `A fragment`, and when the dialog fragment is closed,
I want to switch from `A fragment` to `B fragment` at the same time.

But I keep getting `Fragment already added error`.

I am using `show()` instead of `replace(`) to change the screen.

`Fragment already added error` was easily solved on the web, but
I don't work out weird.

Probably there is a problem with my code, please let me know where the problem is.

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav;
    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    Fragment curFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                curFrag = fm.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
                String tag = String.valueOf(item.getItemId());
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if(curFrag != null) {
                    transaction.hide(curFrag);
                }

                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
                if(fragment == null) {
                    if(id == R.id.list)
                        fragment = new WorkoutListFragment();
                    transaction.add(R.id.content_layout, fragment, tag);
                }
                else {
                    transaction.show(fragment);
                }

                transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
                transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
                transaction.commitNow();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // Method for screen switching
    public void onFragmentChanged() {
//        transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        String tag = "WriteRoutine";

        curFrag = fm.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        if (curFrag != null) {
            transaction.hide(curFrag);
        }

        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new WriteRoutineFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(curFrag.getArguments());
            transaction.add(R.id.content_layout, fragment, tag);
        } else {
            transaction.show(fragment);
        }

        transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

***WorkoutListFragment.java (A Fragment)***

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("result", this, new FragmentResultListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
                if(result != null)
                    WorkoutListFragment.this.setArguments(result);
                    titleData = result.getStringArrayList("title");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_workout_list, container, false);
        initViews(rootView);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar((toolbar));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.record_item_add, menu);
    }

    @Override // open dialog
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        BodyPartDialogFragment dialog = new BodyPartDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "BodyPartDialog");
        return true;
    }
}
```

***DialogFragment.java***

```
public class BodyPartDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Button startBtn;
    ArrayList<String> bodypart_strData;
    int selectedNum;

    final static String TAG = "DialogFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part_dialog, null);
        startBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        
        // A D D
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedNum == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Plaese select", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                    Bundle result = new Bundle();
                    result.putStringArrayList("title", bodypart_strData);
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("result", result);
                    activity.onFragmentChanged();
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon testing your code, you'll just need to reinstantiate the `transaction` object before adding/replacing your fragment.

So, you need to add below in `onFragmentChanged()`:

```
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

And here it is:

```
// Method for screen switching
public void onFragmentChanged() {

    String tag = "WriteRoutine";

    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); // <<< THE CHANGE IS HERE
    curFrag = fm.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    if (curFrag != null) {
        transaction.hide(curFrag);
    }

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new WriteRoutineFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(curFrag.getArguments());
        transaction.add(R.id.content_layout, fragment, tag);
    } else {
        transaction.show(fragment);
    }

    transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much so I solved it. But I'll ask you one question.
I declared the `Transaction variable` to the `member`. This is because in `onNavigation~~()` it is referenced through the fragment manager (beginTransaction()).

So I thought I didn't need to do beginTransaction() again in `onFragmentChanged()`.

Because you already referenced the Transaction in the `onNav~~()` function, it will continue to refer to it.

But I don't understand well that this was a problem.

Can you explain?

Comment: The problem that the `Transaction` local variable state is saved when you make the first transaction, but you know that you can make other transactions in the back stack or clear fragments from it, this can include showing and dismissing the popup dialog.. and therefore the local member transaction variable in the activity will have an old state of the transaction; therefore you need to reinitialize it with the current status of the transaction.. Thanks to accept the answer